# How to I access JSON value from ansible output?

Tags: json, ansible, nested-lists

I have this ansible playbook which will create and attach volumes to EC2 instances using `ec2_vol` module and I want to partition the same using `parted` module. Below is my ec2_vol module,

**EC2_VOL Module:**

```
      ec2_vol:
        aws_access_key: XXXXXXXX
        aws_secret_key: XXXXXXXX
        security_token: XXXXXXXX
        instance: "{{ item.instance_id }}"
        region: "{{ var_dict['REGION'] }}"
        device_name: "{{ VOL_NAME }}"
        volume_type: gp2 
        volume_size: '1000'
        delete_on_termination: false
      with_items: "{{ ec2_instances_list.instances}}"
      register: ec2_volumes    
    - debug:
        msg: "{{ ec2_volumes.results }}"
```

**Result of ec2_volumes:**

And the result that is printing from `ec2_volumes.results`. I want to loop through the **device_name** and partition the devices which is created

```
TASK [debug] *******************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => {
    "msg": [
        {
            "_ansible_ignore_errors": null, 
            "_ansible_item_label": {
                "ami_launch_index": 0, 
                "architecture": "x86_64", 
                "block_device_mappings": [
                    {
                        "device_name": "/dev/sda1", 
                        "ebs": {
                            "attach_time": "2021-04-30T15:47:07+00:00", 
                            "delete_on_termination": true, 
                            "status": "attached", 
                            "volume_id": "vol-XXXXXXXXXXXXXX"
                        }
                    }, 
                    {
                        "device_name": "/dev/sdb", 
                        "ebs": {
                            "attach_time": "2021-04-30T15:47:07+00:00", 
                            "delete_on_termination": false, 
                            "status": "attached", 
                            "volume_id": "vol-XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX"
                        }
                    }
                ],
```

And here is my parted module code:

```
    - name: Partition Additional volumes 
      parted:
        device: "{{ item.block_device_mappings[0].device_name }}"
        number: 1
        part_type: 'primary'
        state: present
        when: ("{{ ec2_volumes.device_name }}" != "/dev/sda1")
      with_items: "{{ ec2_volumes.results}}"
```

But still getting error that 'block_device_mappings' has no attribute.

`fatal: [localhost]: FAILED! => {"msg": "'list object' has no attribute 'block_device_mappings'"}`

What could be the cause? Can someone help me to resolve this issue?

**Edit 1:**

Facing another issue after updating the playbook in the `parted` module

```
    - name: Partition Additional volumes 
      parted:
        device: "{{ item._ansible_item_label.block_device_mappings[0].device_name }}"
        number: 1
        part_type: 'primary'
        state: present
        when: ("{{ ec2_volumes.device_name }}" != "/dev/sda1")
      with_items: "{{ ec2_volumes.results}}"
```

```
fatal: [localhost]: FAILED! => {"msg": "The task includes an option with an undefined variable. The error was: 'dict object' has no attribute 'device_name'
```

Comment: Please review your example to make it [mcve](/help/mcve) because your presented data does not match the vars your are using nor the error your are getting. (i.e. there is no `results` in your data, either as a list or a dict).

Comment: @Zeitounator, can you check now? I am actually debugging the results in which is registered in ec2_vol

Comment: You did not paste a full usable data output and from what is available, I don't see any `block_device_mapping` available in your generated loop `Item`.... altthough `item._ansible_item_label.block_device_mapping` exists... but is basically the item from the previous loop in your previous task...

Comment: Search for block_device_mappings in the output of ec2_vol. You ll get it. FYI, All the tasks are in same play book.. I just shared the output in between for your understanding.

Comment: Full useable data output consists of 1052 lines of code. I cannot post that here, so I posted what I need to do in the next task. Let me know if you can help.

Comment: A piece of one complete json item not cut in the middle would have done

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is clear:

> FAILED! => {"msg": "'list object' has no attribute 'block_device_mappings'"}

When you take a look at the list you'll see that *block_device_mappings* is an attribute of *_ansible_item_label*

```yaml
    "msg": [
        {
            "_ansible_ignore_errors": null, 
            "_ansible_item_label": {
                "ami_launch_index": 0, 
                "architecture": "x86_64", 
                "block_device_mappings": [
                ...
```

Fix the reference

```yaml
    device: "{{ item._ansible_item_label.block_device_mappings[0].device_name }}"
```

Comment: thank you @Vladimir, it worked it seems.. but getting other error now..```fatal: [localhost]: FAILED! => {"msg": "The task includes an option with an undefined variable. The error was: 'dict object' has no attribute 'device_name'```

Comment: Strange. Both ``block_device_mappings.0`` and ``block_device_mappings.1`` got ``device_name``. Find out where this error comes from. [edit] your question and make it [mre].

Comment: Double check ``ec2_volumes.device_name`` exists.